# PHP with CURL -- can you pass custom fields to the form?

Tags: php, forms, curl, post

For example, if you're using curl and want to submit a form, but you want custom fields such `filename="photo"` and `Content-Type: image/jpeg` in the following form submission:

```
--10AE0BB3-605D-4F10-A3C1-D2A18DCB82B9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test_id"

343
--10AE0BB3-605D-4F10-A3C1-D2A18DCB82B9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="photo"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

How do you do this in curl? Here's an example of the code I'm using to set the stuff in the form:

```
function Post($filename) {
        $data = [
            'device_timestamp' => time(), 
            'photo' => file_get_contents($filename)
        ];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

I've tried appending `;filename="photo"` and stuff at the end of `file_get_contents($filename) . ";filename="photo"` for example, but that just doesn't cut it.

I think the last time I tried this a few months ago, I realized it wasn't possible, so I ended up just hardcoding the entire form in the source code of the php file. Not sure if there's any other alternatives.

Here's the function that has the POST information.

```
function Request($url, $post, $data, $userAgent, $cookies) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myurl.com'.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    // Set proxy settings.
    $proxy = '127.0.0.1:8080';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    if($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    return [
        'code' => $http, 
        'response' => $response,
    ];
}
```

Comment: curl itself you want to do it in PHP?where you are using POST function?

Comment: Wanting to do it in PHP using CURL for php. Updating my answer to show the function that has the POST data.

Comment: why cann't you keep the filename as separate index in $data array?

Comment: I can't even add "filename=photo" with the form submission -- I'm not sure how and that's what I'm trying to figure out. It needs to be sent in order for the submission to work properly.